# Second javabean created not being read by Xpages domino designer 10

Tags: xpages, javabeans, lotus-domino, managed-bean

I have just started using managed beans in Xpages. The first bean I created worked perfectly. However any new beans that I create or if I edit the first bean does not reflect when I try to use them in an Xpage. I have tried refreshing the whole application as well as rebuilding. Also, I have ticked refresh whole application on design change in xsp.properties. No idea what else the problem could be.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. To increase your chances of getting an answer, you need to show your code, state what you expected and what you got instead. Without your code, any answer is a guess and nobody wants to guess.

Comment: If you have a compilation error, nothing is updated.